# MySql convert_tz function does not work for timezone codes

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a process that will handle scheduling of jobs with data in the database.  The user can select their timezone when they set the execution date/time for a job.

I need to be able to convert between the timezone of the user to the timezone of the server.

I do not want to hard code the timezone of the server. Please see the code below to see my issue.

*I have checked that timezone tables are available and have data.*

The following query returns only "EDT":

```
select IF(@@session.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@session.time_zone)
```

But I can not pass EDT back into convert_tz successfully. Please the following query to demonstrate my issue.

```
select schedule_time,
time_zone,
convert_tz(schedule_time,'US/Eastern','US/Pacific') 'convert_tz1',
convert_tz(schedule_time,'EST','PST') 'convert_tz2'
from batch_control
```

The following is return:

```
2013-08-27 01:00:00    EST    2013-08-26 22:00:00    NULL
2013-08-26 01:00:00    EST    2013-08-25 22:00:00    NULL
2013-08-26 01:00:00    EST    2013-08-25 22:00:00    NULL
2012-09-28 15:22:00    EST    2012-09-28 12:22:00    NULL
2012-10-15 09:52:00    EST    2012-10-15 06:52:00    NULL
```

I'm confused on why I wouldn't be able to take a timezone value output from mysql itself and pass it back into the convert_tz function.

My final code would be something like this:

```
select convert_tz(schedule_time,time_zone,IF(@@session.time_zone = 'SYSTEM', @@system_time_zone, @@session.time_zone)) 'execute_time'
from batch_control
```